# Confirm form for content type

Tags: 8, forms

I have a custom content type (*books*); on submission of the content type, I want to add a confirmation form for the content type. How can I do that?

How can I append the confirmation form with content type form, and how are the values saved after positive confirmation?

Comment: You could accomplish this with jQuery as shown in my [answer here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203329/how-to-add-a-confirm-dialog-to-node-add-and-edit-forms/205532#205532). Although, my answer is for D7, the same principles will apply for D8.

Comment: Thanks, this we can use. But am checking any Drupal method for that in D8 using form_alter and ConfirmFormBase

Comment: I assume you meant _on submission of the node creation form_. A content type is created from administrator users; it's rather difficult you need a confirmation form for that.

Comment: Yes, but because of its a custom content type we are enabling it for all users, I need a confirmation before they submit to check what they have typed. Is that possible like bulk node delete confirmation and all ?